# React performance issue in Mixin.closeall

Tags: reactjs

I've created a React Application with a grid that you can filter and I used Griddle for my grid and then added a control that shows the number of visible rows when filtering. However, when filtering there is about a 1/2 second delay from when I calculate the new new values to write out and when the update is done by React. As you can see in the gif below the console is writing out logging in my code that goes to the bottom of the stack and then from there it's all React code.

[image: Screen capture]

I profiled this issue in chrome and the results of that are shown in the image below. The top two calls are the last parts of my code. As you can see that code executes quickly and then there is 1/2 a second spent doing the Mixin.closeall call. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

[image: Profile]

Comment: You will find this useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983963/performance-issue-with-react